# Angular - how to render 3 formControlName onto 1 line?

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

Currently the code below render as 3 separate lines.

```html
<div fxLayout="column">
    <label>Some Label</label>
    <mat-form-field class="hide-underline" floatLabel="never">
        <input formControlName="elementA" matInput readonly> 
        <input formControlName="elementB" matInput readonly> 
        <input formControlName="elementC" matInput readonly>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

How could I get to render on one line like: elementA-elementB-elementC instead?

Comment: I misunderstood the question... I updated my answer when using `@angular/flex-layout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a css like display: flex to the mat-form-field to get them rendered in the same line

Answer (score 0):

```
    <mat-form-field class="hide-underline" **class='display:flex'** floatLabel="never">
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `@angular/flex-layout` you should add `fxFlex` on each `<input>` so they get displayed on same line.

```html
<div fxLayout="column">
    <label>Some Label</label>
    <mat-form-field class="hide-underline" floatLabel="never">
        <input fxFlex formControlName="elementA" matInput readonly> 
        <input fxFlex formControlName="elementB" matInput readonly> 
        <input fxFlex formControlName="elementC" matInput readonly>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

> StackBlitz working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-60732248